# Prevent PIL from increasing the size of an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use PIL with python to edit pixels of image to change some values of alpha. Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys

from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('test.png').convert("RGBA")
pixelMap = im.load()

img = Image.new(im.mode, im.size)
pixelsNew = img.load()

for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        pixelsNew[i,j] = pixelMap[i,j]

tmp = pixelsNew[40, 50]
pixelsNew[40, 50] = (tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3] - 1)

img.save('res.png')
```

It works very well but I find that this program makes the image much bigger. For example, I use a `test.png` whose size is just 16KB to do a test. After executing this code, I get the result `res.png`, whose size is 111KB.

Why? Is there a way to decrease the size of the result?

Besides, I also used Photoshop to do the same thing, which means that using Photoshop to change the values of alpha. But Photoshop gives me a result, whose size doesn't change. Is it possible to get the same result with PIL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png), you can pass optional arguments to the `save` method of your `PIL.Image` object.

Although I didn't experience any size changes the order of magnitude you have, the following options yielded lower image sizes in my tests:

```
img.save('res.png', compress_level=9, optimize=True)
```